# How to write a "key" column with seperately with each other column to csv in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

In Python I want to break up one data-frame and write -each "Key","Column" pair to a CSV file. The rows also sometimes contain more than one value per column.

The data-frame looks as follows (the number of columns will not always be the same)

```
col1     col2     key    col3
a        b        c      d
a1       b1       c1     d1,d4
a2       b2,b4    c2     d2
a3       b3       c3     d3
```

What I need is 3 CSV files, looking as follows:

```
col.csv
key    col1
c      a
c1     a1
c2     a2
c3     a3

col2.csv
key    col2
c      b
c1     b1
c2     b2
c2     b4
c3     b3

col3.csv
key    col3
c      d
c1     d1
c1     d4
c2     d2
c3     d3
```

What I've done is write out each column to CSV, with the column name as the CSV, I however cannot get the "key" column to the CSV's.

```
z = df[df_obj.columns]

for c in z.columns:
    df[c].to_csv(cwd + '/split/' + c + '.csv', index=False)
```

What I get is:

```
col1.csv
col1
a
a1
a2
a3

col2.csv
col2
b
b1
b2,b4
b3

col3.csv
col3
d
d1,d4
d2
d3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you mind trying the following. The idea is just to extract the *keys* column out as a separate series first, which you can then use when you iterate over the columns.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

>>>df
col1     col2     key    col3
a        b        c      d
a1       b1       c1     d1,d4
a2       b2,b4    c2     d2
a3       b3       c3     d3

# Create a key series
keys = [r for r in df.key]
# Exclude the keys column from the dataframe
df = df.drop('key', axis=1)

for c in df.columns:
    ser1 = df[c].str.split(',')
    data = pd.DataFrame([(keys[i], j) for i in range(len(keys)) for j in ser1[i]])
    data.to_csv(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),c,'.csv'), index=False)
```

Comment: This created the seperate csv's perfectly, containing the "Key","Column". All that I still need to do is split the values where there is more than one value per row in the column.

Comment: @Ruan Sorry I didn't notice that you requested to flatten the columns as well. I have updated my answer to include that too

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below methods: `set_index`, `stack`, `str.split`, `stack` again, `unstack`, `reset_index`, `reset_index` again, and finally, `to_csv`:

```
z = df[df_obj.columns]

for c in z.columns:

    df[['key', c]].set_index('key')
                  .stack()
                  .str.split(',', expand=True)
                  .stack()
                  .unstack(-2)
                  .reset_index(-1, drop=True)
                  .reset_index()
                  .to_csv(cwd + '/split/' + c + '.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: This gives the error:     return stack(self, level, dropna=dropna)
  File "C:\PYTHON PROGRAMS\ldap\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py", line 507, in stack
    dtype = dtypes[0]
IndexError: list index out of range